# Table returning cumulative sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table. It contains a column with points (a), a column with a playerid (b) and column with games(c). I would like to translate this table using SQL to a format in which values in column a get summed up. This would need to result in the table below. Column d contains the values summed by the previous value, column e contains the playerId en column f the gamenumber

So I would like this:

```
    a      b          c
1   385    11255      1
2   378    11178      1
3   370    11551      1
4   264    11255      2
5   100    11178      2
6   405    11551      2
7   200    11255      3
8   412    11178      3
9   50     11551      3
```

Into this:

```
    d      e          f
    385    11255      1
    649    11255      2
    849    11255      3
    378    11178      1
    478    11178      2
    890    11178      3
    370    11551      1
    775    11551      2
    825    11551      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM() OVER()` window function (if your version of SQL Server supports it)

```
select b,c,sum(a) over(partition by b order by c) as running_sum
from tbl
```

On versions that don't support it, you can do this with `cross apply`.

```
select t.b,t.c,t1.total
from tbl t
cross apply (select sum(a) as total from tbl t1 where t1.b=t.b and t1.c<=t.c) t1
```

Comment: Cross apply seems to do the trick. Except I would like the total column to be in reverse order. Now the largest value in t1.total matches the lowest game number (c) column. For example: f1 for e 11255 returns 849, f2 for e 11255 returns 649, f3 for e 11255 returns 385. I would like f1 to be 385, f2 649 and f3 849. Is such a thing possible as well?

Comment: the condition had to be `t1.c<=t.c` instead of the other way round..i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select sum(a) over (partition by b order by c) as d, b as e, c as f
from t
order by e, f;
```

Cumulative sums with this syntax are supported since SQL Server 2012.